# NSString parameter to action:@selector(ActionMethod:)

Tags: objective-c

Can I pass an integer parameter (an NSString for example) in action:@selector(ActionMethod:)

The action is related to a UIButton

Thanks !

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to call your selector with an integer or NSString parameter. And is the selector being passed into an existing function of UIButton or are you randomly trying to invoke it.

Comment: i would to passe an NSString to a méthod, i can't do it by using button.tag because i would like to pass an NSString. So i ask if i can pass an NSString in @selecteor ...

Comment: You definitely cannot store an NSString in the tag property of a button. You don't pass arguments when creating selectors, and without an example of what you are trying to do I can't help you much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the action methods are called passing in the UIButton (or other UIControl) as the only parameter. However, you can subclass UIButton and add instance variables, then save you string in the button. When the action method is called you can access the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map to save the mapping between tag and NSString. When you want some data from the UIButton, get the tag and then search the mapping table to get the related NSString.